# How click on element with id containing colons in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

Button has id like this `my:very:beautiful:button`

```
<input id="my:very:beautiful:button" type="image" src="https://xxx/search_off.gif" name="my:very:beautiful:button" onmouseout="imgOff('searchBttn', this)" onmouseover="imgOn('searchBttn', this)" class="btn searchBttn" onclick="doSubmit(this, 'clearBttn')">
```

In puppeteer my attempt to click on this button is:

```
await page.click('#my\:very\:beautiful\:button');
```

Throws:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#my:very:beautiful:button' is not a valid selector.
```

With double escape characters:

```
await page.click('#my\\:very\\:beautiful\\:button');
```

Throws:

```
Error: No node found for selector: #my\:very\:beautiful\:button
```

I assume the problem is colon. Any thoughts how click on it?

Comment: I was able to make it work with the second option `await page.click('#my\\:very\\:beautiful\\:button');`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "double escaping" works. The colon should not be the problem.

The problem is most likely that the element simply has not been rendered yet. To wait for the element to be rendered first, you can use the function [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.12.2/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) like this:

```js
const selector = '#my\\:very\\:beautiful\\:button';
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
await page.click(selector);
```

Comment: You are right, it was waiting for some recourse or rendering. `waitForSelector` did not helped, but static sleep for 1 second did the trick `await page.waitFor(1000)`

Answer (score 7):

You can try an attribute selector:

```js
await page.click('[id="my:very:beautiful:button"]');
```